# Running a background task and waiting for its result without blocking the UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, async-await

I want to create a Splash Screen on my WinForms application. I create the splash screen form and run the initialization operation.

```
public async Task RunApplication()
{
    splash = new SplashWindow();
    splash.Show();
    
    await Task.Run(InitializeAsync);
    
    Application.Run(new frmMain());
}

//the InitializeAsync function
private async Task InitializeAsync()
{
   splash.Status = "Test";
}

//the status property
public string Status
{
    get { return status; }
    set {
        if (status != value)
        {
            status = value;
            lblStatus.InvokeIfRequired(() => lblStatus.Text = value);
        }
    }
}

public static void InvokeIfRequired(this ISynchronizeInvoke snc,
                                         MethodInvoker action)
{
    if (snc.InvokeRequired) {
        snc.Invoke(action, null);
    } else {
        action();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to be able to change the label to the current status. However, when I run this code, as soon as I hit the `snc.Invoke(action, null);` line, the program hangs. I did some research/debugging and it seems that when I do `Task.Run`, it will block the UI thread and since the splash has been created on that thread, the program is never able to run that action on the UI thread.

What I ended up doing was to wait until the task is finished and constantly do the application events.

```
var task = Task.Run(InitializeAsync);

while(!task.IsCompleted)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}

Applicaiton.Run(new frmMain());
```

This works. However, I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution for this.

#### Update:

Based on Stephen Cleary's answer, I've changed the code to this but it doesn't work. How can I make it work?

```
//on Program.cs file:
[STAThread]
static async Task Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    await Bootstrapper.RunApplicationAsync();
}

//on Bootstrapper.cs class
private static SplashWindow splash;
public static async Task RunApplicationAsync()
{
  splash = new SplashWindow();
  splash.Show();

  await InitializeAsync();

  Applicaiton.Run(new frmMain());
}

private static async Task InitializeAsync()
{
  splash.Status = "Start";
  await Task.Delay(1000); //program stops here
  splash.Status = "Stop";
}

//on the SplashWindow.cs file
public string Status
{
  get => lblStatus.Text;
  set => lblStatus.Text = value;
}
```

Comment: Never ever ever ever call `Application.DoEvents()`. It is in the framework for backwards compatibility with VB6 code. It can easily create re-entrancy code issue that are nearly impossible to debug.

Comment: @Enigmativity I know that and that's why I'm asking this question. It doesn't feel like it's an elegant solution so I'm looking for a way to get rid of it.

Answer (score 3):

First, get rid of `InvokeIfRequired`. `InvokeRequired` - regardless of how common it is - is a serious code smell.

Instead, you can get rid of `Task.Run` and just call `InitializeAsync` directly:

```
public async Task RunApplication()
{
  splash = new SplashWindow();
  splash.Show();

  await InitializeAsync();

  Applicaiton.Run(new frmMain());
}

private async Task InitializeAsync()
{
  splash.Status = "Test";
}

public string Status
{
  get => lblStatus.Text;
  set => lblStatus.Text = value;
}
```

If you do need to use `Task.Run` for some reason (i.e., if `InitializeAsync` has CPU-bound or blocking work to do), then you can use `Progress<T>`:

```
public async Task RunApplication()
{
  splash = new SplashWindow();
  splash.Show();

  var progress = new Progress<string>(update => splash.Status = update);
  await Task.Run(() => InitializeAsync(progress));

  Applicaiton.Run(new frmMain());
}

private async Task InitializeAsync(IProgress<string>? progress)
{
  progress?.Report("Test");
}

public string Status
{
  get => lblStatus.Text;
  set => lblStatus.Text = value;
}
```

Comment: I need to call that function in another thread because the library that it uses doesn't have async support and it blocks the UI thread. You said I should get rid of `InvokeIfRequired`. What if I'm trying to access the property from another thread? That said, the first part works as expected. However, when I add the `Task.Run` part, even if I remove the entire content of the `InitializeAsync` function, the application cannot go past that line. If I just call it like `await InitializeAsync();` but add a `Task.Run` inside the function, the same thing.

Comment: BTW, I'm running the `RunApplication` function from the `Program.cs` file in a `[STAThread] static async Task Main()` main.

Comment: Please see the update

Comment: Your problem is that you're trying to show a UI without entering the UI main loop (`Application.Run`). You'll need to structure your splash/main forms so that the main loop is entered as normal.

Comment: How would I do that? Could you give me an example?

Comment: I've seen a couple of different approaches. One is to have the splash form actually be your main form, and just hide (not close) when it's done, and have the main form close the splash form when it closes. Another approach is that there's a setting somewhere to tell WinForms to exit only when *all* forms have exited, instead of just the main form.

Comment: None of these seem particularly interesting. Just thought of something. Is it possible to use `Application.Run` for the splash and then call it again with the main form? Would that solve the issue?

Comment: I don't think so, but maybe.